# Change the background image based on data from api (javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, api, background, openweathermap

I'm working on an assignment and I have to make a weather app that has a changing background image on the weather in each city. I'm using the OpenWeatherMap API and I have this code for the images so far

```
var clearsky = new Image();
clearsky.src = "clearsky.jfif";

var clouds = new Image();
clouds.src = "fewclouds.jfif";

var fog = new Image();
fog.src = "fog.jpg";

var rain = new Image();
rain.src = "moderaterain.jpg";

var overcast = new Image();
overcast.src = "overcast.jpg";

var snow = new Image();
snow.src = "snow.jfif";
```

I don't know how to link the images to the weather description from the API. This is what my page looks like [example of the web page that needs image background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhAwF.png) so ideally, the overcast image from my code would be displayed in the bg there since the weather description is "overcast clouds"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and feel free to ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then you need use **HasMap**. For example:

```
HashMap<String, Image> hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put("overcastClouds", overcast)
```